# multiple condition inside SUMIF() in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, formula

I created my daily task log sheet which i log my tasks daily and I also provide the time which I start and the time of its completion. it looks like this

[image]

You'll notice the tab "total hours per day". on that tab I calculate the total time for the specific date. It looks like this

[image]

using this formula: =SUMIF('TASKS (Itemized)'!A3:A501,A8,'TASKS (Itemized)'!I3:I501)

My question is can I still add a condition to the formula that says not to include the time or the row if the column H has a value of "Multitasking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this?

```
=SUMIFS('TASKS (Itemized)'!I3:I,'TASKS (Itemized)'!A3:A,A8,'TASKS (Itemized)'!H3:H,"<>Multitasking")
```

Without seeing a sample sheet of everything going on including columns and rows this is the best I can offer.